# Selenium method visibilityOf - Doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When i used the listed method to see whether an element is visible on the page, I get an exception stating that its **unable to locate an element using the specified locator.**

Any ideas, has anyone faced this issue before or even have a better method?

```
    public boolean isElementPresentByWebElement(WebElement element) {
    Wait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        try {
            fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
            System.out.println("Element is visible: " + element.toString());
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Unable to locate the element: " + element.toString() + ", Exception: " + e.toString());
            throw (e);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @anderson please find html code attatched

Comment: @Andersson please find html code attatched

Comment: can you let me know which exception you have imported. it should be org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is overly complicated for what you are trying to do. There is a built in class, `ExpectedConditions`, that will do what you want. You are also looping over the wait which is unnecessary. I would suggest that you pass in a locator (`By`) instead of a `WebElement`. It will expand your ability to use this function because you won't have to find the element before using the function.

```
public boolean isElementPresentByLocator(By locator)
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        System.out.println("Element is visible: " + locator.toString());
        return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to locate the element: " + locator.toString() + ", Exception: " + e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code below is more of a direct translation and simplification of your code.

```
public boolean isElementPresentByWebElement(WebElement element)
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        System.out.println("Element is visible: " + element.toString());
        return true;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to locate the element: " + element.toString() + ", Exception: " + e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Updated :**

try using following :

```
 int waitCounter  = 0;

 public static void WaitUntilVisible(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
try {


    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);


    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elementToBeClicked));
    if (!elementToBeClicked.isDisplayed()) {

        System.out.println("Element not visible yet. waiting some more for " + element);
        if (waitCounter < 3) {
            waitCounter++;
            WaitUntilVisible(element);
        }
        waitCounter = 0;
    }

} catch (Exception e)

{
    System.out.println("Handling exception");
}
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile. You are using several undeclared variables and you've introduced `Logger_Info()` which has not been defined.

Comment: you just have to initialize 'waitcounter=0' and instead of 'logger_info' use ' System.our.println '